# Using sed to remove multiple hashtags

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm writing a bash script on OSX. There's a lot of grep and sed going on, all working fine, with one exception: I can't figure out how to remove multiple hashtags.

This removes ALL hashtags, no problem:

```
sed 's/#[^ ]*//g'
```

I expected this to remove specific hashtags:

```
sed "s/#(tag1|tag2)//g"
```

But it doesn't remove anything.

I thought the # symbol might be a special character so I tried without:

```
sed "s/(tag1|tag2)//g"
```

It makes no difference, neither tag1 nor tag2 are removed.

But if I try:

```
sed "s/tag1//g"
```

Then tag1 is removed, leaving the #.

If I then try:

```
sed "s/#tag1//g"
```

Nothing happens! It doesn't remove tag1 or #tag1.

Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong please?

EDIT: This is the code:

```
results=($( \
echo "$ContentsOfHTMLFile" \
| sed -E "s/#(tag1|tag2|tag3)//g" \
| grep -iEo "<p.*>.*$VariableContainingSearchTerms\D.*</p>" \
| grep -iEo "<p.*>.*$VariableContainingSearchTerms.*</p>" \
| grep -Ev $VariableContainingSearchTermsToExclude \
| sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' \
| sed 's/http[^ ]*//g' \
| sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' \
| sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' \
))
```

So what I'm trying to do is:

1. Remove certain hashtags.
2. Search for `<p></p>` blocks that contain certain terms.
3. Only keep the blocks that contain certain other terms.
4. Strip all `<>` blocks.
5. Strip all URLs.
6. Strip all leading whitespace.
7. Strip all trailing whitespace.

Everything from 2-7 works as it should. It's just the hashtags I'm having a problem with. I've also tried doing the hashtags at other points in the sequence, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Use the -E flag for sed, then your "OR" operator will work.

Comment: I can't reproduce your last result, `echo "This is text with #tag1 and #tag2" | sed "s/#tag1//g"` on macOS gives me `This is text with  and #tag2`

Comment: How strange: Everything seems to work fine on the command line (including -E to enable the OR operator) but not in the bash script...

Comment: Both are /usr/bin/sed

Comment: It shouldn't matter in this case, but you should use single quotes around regexes in general.  The last four `sed` commands can be combined into one (which has major merits if the files are big).  Either use `sed -e '…rx1…' -e '…rx2…' …` or combine the regexes into one single argument: `sed -e '…rx1…; …rx2…; …rx3…; …rx4…'`.  None of which directly affects your problem.

Comment: That's very useful information though Jonathan, thank you.

Comment: wrt `There's a lot of grep and sed going on` - uh-oh. I see your starting point is `echo "$ContentsOfHTMLFile" | ...` - there is certainly a better way to parse your HTML than a series of greps+seds. If you'd like help with that then post a new question with it's own [mcve] showing a sample HTML file and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -E 's/#(tag1|tag2)//g'
```

From sed's help:

```
  -E, -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script
                 (for portability use POSIX -E).
```

Comment: Note that POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)
does not yet define `-E`. However, `-E` is understood the same by GNU `sed` and BSD (macOS) `sed`, so it is the better choice for more nearly portable scripting.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX standard `sed` does not support `|` in regex, you can use two `s`es instead, like this:

```
sed -e 's/#tag1//g;s/#tag2//g;'
```

Or

```
sed -e 's/#tag1//g;' -e 's/#tag2//g;'
```

Btw, it also needs to use `\(` and `\)` to group things.
`(` and `)` will match the parens literally.